# If an Ashkenazi Jew moves to a sefardic country with no Ashkenazi community, does he need to adopt their customs?

Tags: minhag

Based off of Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim [Siman 468 Sayif 4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2241).

For example, did the Rosh become sefardic when he moved to Spain?

Comment: The Rosh did not become Sephardi. Instead he turned them into Ashkenazim! Their Moroccan descendants still follow Ashkenazi halakha.

Comment: I wouldn't say he turned them ashkenazi, but there was a definite blend. Perhaps seen best in his son's turim where ashkenazi and sefardi laws are presented side by side. Moroccans also stradle the line between the two. To quote Rabbi Lancry of Brooklyn 'we Moroccans are wishy washy'.

Comment: @user6591 Either way, (and yes I was oversimplifying the better part of a millennium's shifting cultural history), the point remains essentially the same. The Rosh and his successors did not assimilate into their host culture. Quite the contrary.

Comment: Yishaq, according to the rosh's son yehuda in his memoirs, the jews in Spain were extremely  unlearned. The only field they excelled in was dikduk. I don't think they felt any need to join a community of unlearned people. On the flip note, the Aruch Hashulchan's family, acc to his son's memoirs, trace their lineage to a sefardi family benibitechi. They did switch to Ashkenaz way back when.

Comment: Mevaqesh, I'm just joining the conversation.

Comment: @mevaqesh, the Rosh paskened for the Sephardim following their rabbanim (ie. Rishonim) although he followed Minhog Rheinus himself. R' Hamburger שליט”א quotes his teshuvah (שו”ת הראש 20:20) in שרשי מנהג אשכנז to support the opinion that Yeckes should not acclimate to the Eastern Ashkenazi minhagim, although its original context is protecting Ashkenazim holding like our poskim in Sepharad.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I don't know that there were no occasions of that, but there were certainly occasions of the opposite, cf. Shu"t HaRosh (21:8). For discussion of this as part of a larger phenomenon, see Hakham Dr. Jose Faur's [Anti-Maimonidean Demons](http://www.chayas.com/AntiRAMBAM.pdf).

Comment: @mevaqesh i couldn't bring myself to read that whole article. Where exactly does he mention the Rosh?

Comment: @user6591 p. 31. I must provide provide a trigger warning to those who may be offended by the politically incorrect, one sided presentation.

Comment: @mevaqesh more than politically incorrect. Ironic is more like it. Citing Graetz as a main source and accusing all those holy rabbis of being influenced by Christianity is befuddling.

Comment: @user6591 This conversation can continued elsewhere, as it is not directly related to the question at hand.